# class Qlabel has no member named 'ans'

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a gui that allows you to input 3 variables and press a button that calculates an answer from an equation. I am brand new to this so I am still trying to figure out what is happening. The error gives me

> "class Qlabel has no member named 'ans'"

when I try to use the `line ui->equation->ans;`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_NtButton_clicked();

    void on_N0Button_clicked();

    void on_kButton_clicked();

    void on_tButton_clicked();

    void on_quitButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int N;
    int N0;
    int k;
    int t;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_N0Button_clicked()
{
    QString N0 = ui->lineEdit_2->text();

}

void MainWindow::on_kButton_clicked()
{
    QString k = ui->lineEdit_3->text();
}

void MainWindow::on_tButton_clicked()
{
    QString t = ui->lineEdit_4->text();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
    int ans = N*t == N0*10^(k*t);
    ui->equation->ans;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    /*QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Quit the program!");
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    button->show();
    */
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: What is "`ui->equation->ans`"? If `ui->equation` is `QLabel`, then you may read Qt documentation about what members has `QLabel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ans is just no method of QLabel. ans is your variable. You probably want to set the value in the QLabel:

```
ui->equation->setText(QString::number(ans));
```

Read the documentation for more help. The Qt Docs are pretty well organized so you should have no problems finding your desired action.